# Segmentation fault in cross-linked vectors

Tags: c++

I'm trying to have a vector of students and a vector of universities, where each student has a list of universities he is applying to and each university has a list of students, that applied.
But when I run the code, "Segmentation fault: 11" happens. Can you, please, help me understand, where I'm doing wrong.

```
struct Student;

struct Univercity
{
    std::string name;
    int vacancies;
    std::vector<Student *> students;

    Univercity(std::string name,
               int vacancies)
        : name(name),
          vacancies(vacancies) {}
};

struct Student {
    std::string name, surname;
    int d, m, y;
    int points;
    std::vector<Univercity *> univercities;

    Student(std::string name,
            std::string surname,
            int d, int m, int y, int points,
            std::vector<Univercity *> univercities)
        : name(name),
          surname(surname),
          d(d), m(m), y(y),
          univercities(univercities) {}
};

void input(std::vector <Student> *students,
           std::vector <Univercity> *univercities) {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::string name;
        int vacancies;
        std::cin >> name >> vacancies;
        univercities->push_back(Univercity(name, vacancies));
    }
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::string name, surname;
        int d, m, y, points;
        int k;
        std::vector<Univercity *> applications;
        std::string uni_name;
        std::cin >> name >> surname >> d >> m >> y >> points >> k;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            std::cin >> uni_name;
            for (auto u : *univercities) {
                if (u.name == uni_name) {
                    applications.push_back(&u);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        students->push_back(Student(name, surname, d, m, y,
                                    points, applications));
    }

}

int main() {
    std::vector <Univercity> univercities;
    std::vector <Student> students;
    input(&students, &univercities);
    for (auto s : students) {
        std::cout << s.surname << " " << s.univercities.size() << "\n";
        for (auto u : s.univercities) {
            std::cout << u->name << " " << u->vacancies << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Sample input:

```
3
MSU 1
HSE 2
MIPT 100
5
Ivan Ivanov 1 1 1900 100 2 MSU HSE
Petr Petrov 2 1 1900 90 2 MSU HSE
Alexander Sidorov 3 1 1900 110 2 MIPT HSE
Ivan Petrov 3 1 1900 100 3 HSE MSU MIPT
Petr Ivanov 4 1 1900 80 1 HSE
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Haven't your teacher taught you how to pass arguments by reference? And are you required to use `std::vector`? It looks like a `std::map` might have been better to map a name to a university. Perhaps a map to pointers to the universities used just inside the `input` function, so you don't have to use the manual loop to find universities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read the input you have:

```
for (auto u : *univercities) {
    if (u.name == uni_name) {
        applications.push_back(&u);
        break;
    }
}
```

In the ranged based for loop `u` is a copy of the element in the vector. Thus the adresses you push into the vector are invalid once you leave the loop. Use

```
for (auto& u : *univercities) { //...
```

to use references and avoid making copies.

Comment: seems like I can remove the disclaimer in the beginning ;)

Answer (score 0):

`applications.push_back(&u);`

You are pushing to `applications` a pointer to `univercities`'s element. But `univercities` cease to exist at the end of the `input` function (and so all its content). So after that pointers in `application` vector doesn't point to existing objects.

Btw.: "universities", not "univercities".

**Edit: I was wrong. Vector is passed by pointer so it still exist. Didn't notice the asterisk, sorry.**

Comment: the pointers are already invalid at the end of the loop (more specifically at the end of each single iteration) not at the end of the `input` function

Comment: Yea, I just realised after reading your answer. But even with reference in for loop, it will be as I said above.

Comment: no it wont, because the reference is to the element in the vector

Comment: the vector `universities` is passed by reference (ie via pointer), thus it is fine to use pointers to its elements inside the function

Comment: But the vector was copied when it was passed to the function and the copy won't exist when the function ends.


@tobi303 "the vector universities is passed by reference (ie via pointer), thus it is fine to use pointers to its elements inside the function" oh, didn;t notice the asterisk... Never mind.